# Server and Application uptime monitoring

Tags: linux, open-source, monitoring

I'm actually using phpservermon for monitoring uptime of my server/services. I'm looking for something slightly better, in order to:

- monitor through ping too; (phpservermon only allows curl method)
- better alarms scheduling (phpservermon only allows once or persistent)

Please avoid solutions as zabbix, nagios, spiceworks, etc. They're all too much complicated for such small environment, and I'd like to keep the following as with phpservermon is:

- free software
- agentless
- linux & web based
- not part of a third party's cloud services